# Convert JSON to Powershell Object prints Strange Output

Tags: json, api, powershell

at the moment i am struggling with an api. 
I try to read the informations from an api and work in powershell with those informations. The API is a JSON.
The Problem is that it always has this "@{label=id; value=" double informations and after that some values are NULL but there should be informations in it.
Thank you in advance.

Hope that's understandable :)

```
## Parameter ##
$clientID = "ABCD"
$clientSecret = "EVGH"
$urlAPI = "https://api.url.de/..."

try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri ("https://api.url.de/v1/auth?client_id=" + $clientID + "&client_secret=" + $clientSecret) -Method POST  -ErrorAction stop
}
catch {Write-Host "Webrequest broke"}

$token = $result.data
$token = $token.token

$header = @{Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $token}
try {
    $result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -URI $urlAPI  -Headers $header -ErrorAction stop 
}
catch {Write-Host "Webrequest 2 broke"}

$result.data.attributes
```

The Information it gets should look like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":[{
    {"type":"Employee","attributes":
        {"id":
            {"label":"id","value":999999},
        "first_name":
            {"label":"First name","value":"John"},
        "last_name":
            {"label":"Last name","value":"Doe"},
        "position":
            {"label":"Position","value":"Employee"},
        "hire_date":
            {"label":"Hire date","value":"2001-01-01T00:00:00+02:00"},
        "subcompany":
            {"label":"Subcompany","value":
                {"type":"Subcompany","attributes":
                    {"id":1234,"name":"Company"}}},
        "department":
            {"label":"Department","value":
                {"type":"Department","attributes":
                    {"id":23456,"name":"Department-Superfun"}}}
}}}]}
```

The return from $result.data.attributes looks like this:

```
id               : @{label=id; value=999999}
first_name       : @{label=First name; value=John}
last_name        : @{label=Last name; value=Doe}
position         : @{label=Position; value=Employee}
hire_date        : @{label=Hire date; value=2001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00}
subcompany       : @{label=Subcompany; value=}
department       : @{label=Department; value=}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are seeing is actually correct. If you look at the structure of the data, attributes is an object that has properties id, first_name, last_name, etc. The value of those properties are themselves objects, which have their own properties. For example, the value of attributes.id is an object having properties label and value.

In the case of subcompany, it has a property called value, whose value is an object. PowerShell does not display the content of nested objects by default, but if you try to access the properties using PowerShell they will exist. Same goes for department.